# How to do linear regression with this particular data set?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a response variable `y`.
Also I have a list of 5 dependent variables

```
x <- list(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)
```

Lastly I have a Logical Vector z of length 5. E.g.

```
z <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

Given this I want R to automatically do linear Regression

```
lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x5)
```

Basically the TRUE/FALSE correspond to whether to include the dependent variable or not.
I am unable to do this.
I tried doing `lm(y ~x[z])` but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do

```
lm(y ~ do.call(cbind, x[z]))
```

`do.call(cbind, x[z])` will convert `x[z]` into a matrix, which is an acceptable input format for `lm`. One problem with this is that the names of the regressors (assuming that `x` is a named list) in the output are a little messy. So, instead you may do

```
lm(y ~ ., data = data.frame(y = y, do.call(cbind, x[z])))
```

that would give nice names in the output (again, assuming that `x` is a named list).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like binding your y to a data.frame or matrix (cbind) before you do your linear regression. You can filter your dependent variables by doing something like this:

```
x <- list(x1 = 1:5, x2 = 1:5, x3 = 1:10, x4 = 1:5, x5 = 1:5)
z <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
b <- data.frame(x[which(z == TRUE)])
```